# Choosing an arrays size and populate it with user input

Tags: java, arrays, jcreator

The user writes in how many numbers that is going to be in the array and then the user writes in the numbers himself. Im not sure on how to write the code for this.

(The numbers is not supposed to be generated. Sorry for the swedish words.).

The point of the code is to find a number that is in the array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Sok1 {

    public static void main (String[] args ) {

        System.out.println("Hur många nummer ska din lista bestå av?";
        int ListaLength = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<=ListaLength i++){
            int array
            array[i]=
            //This is where i am stuck.^^^^

        }
    } 

System.out.println("Skriv in ditt första nummer.");
int Lista1 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("Skriv in ditt andra nummer.");
int Lista2 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("Skriv in ditt tredje nummer.");
int Lista3 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("Skriv in ditt fjärde nummer.");
int Lista4 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("Skriv in ditt femte nummer.");
int Lista5 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

//This is the part of code that i removed because the new code is replacing it



    System.out.println("Skriv in numret du letar efter.");
    int element = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    System.out.println(" ");

    int[] myList = {Lista1,Lista2,Lista3,Lista4,Lista5};

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if (myList[i] == element)
            System.out.println ("Din siffra är på plats " +(i+1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: this code wont compile. even without the part where you are stuck

Comment: @JBNizet Im wondering on how im supposed to write the array...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to create an array from user input then check if the array contains a number the user gives you? Or do you want to check if a number (given by the user) is in a predefined (by the program) array?

Comment: I want the user to put in the ammount of numbers that he chooses and then choose what these numbers are and then he puts in a number and the code writes out where that number is.

Comment: @PhilippSander I have added the part of code that was missing for it too compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to take the array size from user and then user input elements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hur många nummer ska din lista bestå av?");
    int ListaLength = s.nextInt();
    Integer array[] = new Integer[ListaLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaLength; i++) {     
        array[i] = s.nextInt();

    }
    for(int i : array){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("Skriv in numret du letar efter.");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(num);
    System.out.println(index);

}
```

Comment: Can you please brief that what issue you are facing in this?

Comment: The code that you wrote doesnt search for the number?

Comment: Oh nvm. Its just that "Skriv in numret du letar efter." actually means "write in the number you're looking for" and you're not swedish so you didnt know that and thats why i got confused.

Comment: I have modified the code as per your requirement.Please is this code fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to create the array just construct a new array with the required size like so:

`int[] array = new int[ListaLength];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class A{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Size : ");

    int Size=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());


    int array[] =new int[Size];

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Number : ");
        array[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.print("\narray : ");

    for(int x:array)
        System.out.print(x+" ");

}
}
```

and don't create new instance of a scanner each time. you can easily reuse it